# initialize variable inside subscribe (rxjs) always undefined Angular 6

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I have been working for a few months with Angular 6. I have two components:
the first one (parent) has to read a parameter by http request and initialize inner attribute; the second one (child) takes this parameter using @Input decorator on its own attribute. I cannot set the parent attribute in subscribe method, the attribute is undefined.
Any suggestion?

Parent component:

```
export class DeliberaComponent implements OnInit {

  private categoria: string = 'delibera';
  private prefix: string;

  constructor(private sistemaService: SistemaService) {
    this.sistemaService.readCategoriaAttributes(this.categoria)
    .subscribe(categoria => {
      this.prefix = categoria.listCategoriaAttribute.filter(attr => attr.chiave === 'prefixNamePdv').pop().valore; 
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
export class CreazioneManualeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  private prefix: string;
  private idpdv: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.idpdv = 
    this.prefix.concat(newDate().toDateString());
  }
}
```

This is the html fragment:

```
<sa-creazione-manuale [categoria]="categoria" [prefix]="prefix"></sa-creazione-manuale>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the information via http, there is no way you have a response before your child component has been created, therefore, when ngOnInit runs there is no prefix.

you can do this....

```
    ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChanges) {
        If (change.prefix) {
            this.idpdv = 
            this.prefix.concat(newDate().toDateString());
        }
    }
```

but that is pretty expensive since it will check the if every time changeDetection runs on your child component.... If you can a better alternative would be to just add the date to your string directly in the subscribe of the parent component. You can also create a pure pipe that will do it for you if you use it in the child component's html.

Answer (score 0):

After @Tzannetos Philippakos explanation I found a working solution:

```js
export class DeliberaComponent implements OnInit {

  private categoria: string = 'delibera';
  private prefix: string;
  @ViewChild(CreazioneManualeComponent)
  private childCreazioneManuale: CreazioneManualeComponent;

  constructor(private sistemaService: SistemaService) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.sistemaService.readCategoriaAttributes(this.categoria)
    .subscribe(categoria => {
      let prefix = categoria.listCategoriaAttribute.filter(attr => attr.chiave === 'prefixNamePdv').pop().valore;
      this.childCreazioneManuale.setPrefix(prefix); 
    });
  }
}
```

In Child component:

```js
 setPrefix(prefix: string){
    this.idpdv = prefix.concat(new Date().toDateString());
    this.headerForm.controls['idpdv'].setValue(this.idpdv)
  }
```

Html:

```
<sa-creazione-manuale [categoria]="categoria" ></sa-creazione-manuale>
```